# VTiger - Custom field with a DB value

Tags: php, mysql, crm, vtiger

I need to create a custom field into contacts module. But this field must not be editable. It have a value from a database query.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities. 
First:
Create the customfield with vTiger and update your database query
Second:
Create the field in Database. Alter the Tyble vtiger_contacts with your custom field. Add a entry in vtiger_fields and link it with the new column in vtiger_contacts. in the field table you can set a flag for disable the field.